# Building management company: Can I be charged for something not my responsibility?

Tags: united-kingdom, contract-law

Can a building management company charge me for work - cleaning up, fixes, etc. - that are the result of other residents' actions?

Eg If another resident(s) makes a large mess in a common area and there's a cost to clean it up - is it fair (correct legal term?) for me to be expected to pay?

Comment: No, 'fair' is not a term recognised by law. Whether it is *legal* depends on your contract with the company.

Answer (score -3):

Technically, if there is no proof or evidence that you didn't make that mess or the action they're trying to make you pay for, or evidence of the guilty one; yes, is commonly fair-use to make everyone pay for a single guilty mess of things. 
 Take for example the school system: everyone is forced on not going to the trip because someone made the principal angry on that class.

Comment: That's...not how the law works.

Comment: Right, but the law, at least here where I live in Italy, states that if someone in the morning wake up with the bad feet and point their fingers at you saying that you stole them money, if you, the "offender" don't have any proof that you did NOT what they say you did, you are guilty by default. (I mean that here there is a "lack of evidence" statement that's totally different from "acquitted" instead, so judges are not sure on both the parties but keep in mind the dispute forever so you're a little more tracked even if you did absolutely nothing, for your entire life).

Comment: @Polygnome Here were I live is not this way.. I was used to stay near a lot of children, both genders, and when no one said a word a very good morning one of the parents of one of them decided to have a bad day and reported me for harassment on their child. Every other kindergarten child reported that they never saw anything I did or say to them, by the way the daughter of the bad morning parent did't say a word so "benefit of the doubt man" but now my name is in the mind of the judges for my life and I'm also not permitted anymore to stay in there and forced to change home. "just in case"..

Comment: The question is tagged with the United Kingdom tag. As such answers should be based on applicable law, not the law that is local to the person providing the answer.

Comment: @Jason Aller sorry about that, I thought it was similar to the rest of the world because some friends of mine told me a similar story in Australia about a street fight or something like that where they were all imprisoned for about a month..